# Search and select multiple cells in vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a userforum to search specific keywords and to select all the cells containing that information and to copy and paste the entire row into another sheet. So far I only know how to select one cell/row at a time. This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells.Find(What:=searchbox1.Text, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:= True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    sheets(2).activate
```

Comment: see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105313/deleting-rows-of-data-not-needed/38105606#38105606).... very similar concept

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to filter through 100's of thousands of line, a simple loop will do the same job as the find.

Adapt this code to your workbook, it loops through the range you want to test against your `textbox` and copies every match to the range of your choice.

```
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim destRng As Range

   Set rng = Range("A1:A20")

  For Each r In rng
      If r.Value = searchbox1.Text Then
        If Not destRng Is Nothing Then
           Set destRng = Union(r.EntireRow, destRng)
        Else
           Set destRng = r.EntireRow
        End If
      End If
  Next r
      destRng.Copy sheets(2).Range("A1")
```